# Multidimensional python arrays

Tags: python

Why does the following code

```
A = [[[0] * 3] * 3] * 3
A[2][2][2] = 1

print A
```

print this

```
[[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]]
```

instead of just setting one of the elements to 1?

Comment: This is a duplicate of many questions; I chose one at random.   See the [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common question;

```
[0] * 3
```

results in a list containing three 0s, *but*

```
[[]] * 3
```

results in a list containing three references to a single actual list.

You need to do something like

```
A = [[[0] * 3] for j in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
```

to actually create what you want.